# Python PyCryptodome Digital Signature Algorithm with DSS

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, pycryptodome, dsa

[in Python Pycryptodome default example for DSA-DSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy7Vf.jpg)
Hi guys.I asked this question but , it's not clever , I deleted on my profile and just asking from my friends account.

Problem is that .I tried to use public key encryption , signature , verifiying , so..

Till tomorrow all's going well but I encounter with DSA-DSS ECDSA. If you look at picture , I think there some issue that I target it.They makes "signer" with private key in DSS , but they don't uses it in signature. Instead it using key sign .Even at verifying level , (in picture didn't appear) they call public key from "PEM" file and trying to verify without call DSS new() again..

So if you compare my code and picture then you notice actually what I want to say...

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
from Crypto.Signature import DSS
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
key = DSA.generate(2048)
publickey=key.publickey()
message = b"Hello"
hash_obj = SHA256.new(message)
signer = DSS.new(key, 'fips-186-3')
signature = signer.sign(hash_obj)
```

So here I trying to verify message..I did't create has object again,and I called public key from key that I showed it above.

```
pkey=DSS.new(publickey,'fips-186-3')
pkey.verify(hash_obj,signature)
False
```

So as you can see , I got "False" .I tried it on ECDSA - DSS returned samething again.
so if you got what I want to do , please help , what I want to to?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs for the `verify` method](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/dsa.html#Crypto.Signature.DSS.DssSigScheme.verify) say:

> **Raises:**  **ValueError** – if the signature is not authentic

and it always return `False` if it is successful.

So rather than checking the return value, you need to check if the method raises an exception.

In general you will want something like:

```
try:
    pkey.verify(hash_obj,signature)
    valid = True
except ValueError:
    valid = False
```

In your code the fact that it doesn’t raise an exception shows that the verification has succeeded and the signature is in fact valid.

Comment: Thanks.I noticed it , this morning I examine DSS file  , I saw at the end of  Verify block that return False.I thought that if program is passing all block succesfully  till return , then it was supposed to be True,why they did such a confuse I dount figure it out